# Using an external MySQL database from Google App Engine & Django

Tags: mysql, django, google-app-engine

We would like to use Google App Engine for a Django project for rapid development and scalable deployment. We'd also like to use an existing MySQL server as a database. In theory this would eliminate the problems with using the Google App Engine storage solutions and Django.

Unfortunately, although the app works locally, I get the following error when I deploy:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

From posts by people wanting to do this with Java I understand that I can't open a MySQL port from GAE. This being the case, is there a drop-in solution for accessing a remote MySQL database (using a technique like tunnelling over HTTP) in Python that would let me keep using the Django ORM features?

Comment: Rather than accessing your existing MySQL database, why not port to BigTable using [djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine)?

Comment: Thanks, but it is a business requirement that we use SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access your own Mysql, however you can use [Google cloud Sql](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/developers_guide_python#deploy_your_application_to_google_app_engine).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the Google Cloud SQL solution is in Beta:

  "  `Spaces in the program are currently limited, with a wait time of at least 2 weeks. We are currently prioritizing providing spaces for existing Google App Engine Java and Python projects.`  "

This isn't acceptable as we have no current GAE app in place and we need to start development now. Using this service would be a wait of 2 weeks at least, with no guarantee of acceptance.

Comment: @darkfader: You can develop against a local MySQL environment whilst awaiting your invitation.

Comment: I could. But with no guarantee of getting on the service and no official release date I wouldn't feel comfortable recommending that as a solution.

Comment: Just apply for the Beta. I got mine in less than a week. That was a year ago though.

Comment: OK. Despite the questions and explanatory text being heavily weighted against new Google App Engine users, I have applied - using 0 in many boxes. (Like 'current database size').

I'll report back with any result, but unless there's another way of doing this (similar to that in the original question) I still can't recommend it as a viable solution.

Comment: I'm setting this as the 'accepted' answer as... Well, what I want to do doesn't seem to be possible. I'm moving to another provider (Heroku) for now, until the GAE team accept me into Google Cloud SQL or they make the service public.

(Been a while hasn't it?)